# Scrolling problem using HTML5 Boilerplate in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html, scroll

I am developing a page based on HTML5 Bolierplate. However, I have a problem. IE does not scroll the page correctly; this issue is most apparent in the display of my div content.

My CSS : http://pastebin.com/kmU7rSLd

And my html: http://pastebin.com/6D47Fwkg

Any ideas on what may be causing the problem? I have tried to fix it for several hours now, but to no avail.

Comment: What does "does not scroll the page correctly" mean exactly? What happens?

Comment: A live demo would be much more useful. If you can't provide one, try [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Don't have IE available, but I give it a shot anyway :)

You have invalid html:

```
</span class="companyRolls">
```

And that might cause IE to act weird.